# how to upload and save file to parse.com

Tags: javascript

trying to upload a file and save it to an object in parse.com using javascript.

form code:

```
 <input type="file" id="PhotoFileUpload" name="PhotoFileUpload">
```

JavaScript cloud code:

```
 var fileUploadControl = [];
  fileUploadControl = req.body.PhotoFileUpload[0];
  if (fileUploadControl.files[0].length > 0) {
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
    var name = "photo.jpg";

    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
    parseFile.save();
```

i am getting the error:

```
 Result: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    Line:  if (fileUploadControl.files[0].length > 0) {
```

Any idea?

Comment: `fileUploadControl = req.body.PhotoFileUpload[0];` This line is not doing anything. Debug why `req.body.PhotoFileUpload[0]` is undefined.

Comment: the line fileUploadControl = req.body.PhotoFileUpload[0]; is how i get the file from the html form using cloud code, the same as i get any other input field from the form.  i did try to debug, i pasted the error i get from the parse console when i submit the form.

Comment: Anyone out there can help!